# Why is this looping forever?

Tags: loops

```
string confirm = "";

                    while (confirm != "y" || confirm != "n")
                    {
                        Console.Write("Remove {0}' account? (Y/N): ", Accounts[accountNumber].Name);
                        confirm = Console.ReadLine();
                        confirm = confirm.ToLower();
                    }
```

For some unknown reason my loop fails on the check. Even if confirm IS either "n" or "y" it will still loop round again. I have even checked it is definitely matched to either "n" or "y" by using a break-point. So why is this failing the check each time?

Comment: Do you mean that it is always in the loop, or that it is never in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your string cant be both `y` and `n`. Replace the `||` with `&&`:

```
while (confirm != "y" && confirm != "n")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (confirm != "y" || confirm != "n")
```

You will loop whilst your string is *either* NOT `y`, or NOT `n`. If it's `n`, then it's NOT `y`, and vice versa. You can't satisfy both conditions at the same time!

You need

```
 while (confirm != "y" && confirm != "n")
```

which will be satisfied if your string is something other than `y` or `n`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a wrong logic: if for example confirm is "y", it's not equal "n", so it will enter anyway in your loop.

Do this:

```
while (!(confirm == "y" || confirm =="n")){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DrOstler,

Your logic is wrong.

For me ir helps if you think in binary.

0 OR 0 is the only false one while 0 OR 1, 1 OR 1, 1 OR 0 are all true.
0 OR 0 means that your or answer has to be y and n, which is impossible.

What you need is to use the AND operator (&&) or use equality instead of negation.

```
while (confirm != "y" && confirm != "n")
```

this only loops as long as there an answer that is neither y nor n.

OR

```
while (confirm == "y" || confirm == "n")
```

this only loops if the answer is either y or n.

Hint: Google morgan laws!